# SQLSTATE[23000] Can't add configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, database, indexing

We're unable to add configurable products to our website anymore, when we try to we get the following error in our Magento *exception.log*.

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000] [1062] Duplicate entry '2231-1' for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID', query was: INSERT INTO `cataloginventory_stock_item` (`product_id`, `stock_id`, `qty`, `is_in_stock`, `use_config_manage_stock`, `use_config_qty_increments`, `use_config_enable_qty_inc`, `is_decimal_divided`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' in /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute()
#1 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute()
#2 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute()
#3 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query()
#4 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query()
#5 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(576): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query()
#6 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert()
#7 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save()
#8 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(159): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->saveInventoryData()
#10 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod()
#11 /var/www/magento-root/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent()
#12 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent()
#13 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php(549): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#14 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product->_afterSave()
#15 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(728): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#16 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->saveAction()
#17 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch()
#18 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match()
#19 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /var/www/magento-root/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run()
#21 /var/www/magento-root/index.php(89): Mage::run()
#22 {main}
```

Also we are unable to re-index our *Product Flat Data* and we just get the message...

> There was a problem with reindexing process.

From the command line I get more detail. . .

```
# php indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`magento_root`.`#sql-921_2c6865`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON D)' in /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `rr...', Array)
#5 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `rr...', Array)
#6 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(423): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `rr...')
#7 /var/www/magento-root/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2833): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `rr...')
#8 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(815): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_...', 'catalog_pro...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_pro...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1389): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(350): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /var/www/magento-root/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php(168): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /var/www/magento-root/shell/indexer.php(216): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

I was exporting the db yesturday and by accident I believe started to to execute a sql db dumb on the database rather than dump the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked our list of products in **Catalog > Manage Products** and saw that the highest ID was 2227 so I removed all records from our `cataloginventory_stock_item` & `catalog_product_flat` that had a product_id > 2227.

After that it began working.

Comment: This would mean, that your autoincrement IDs where gone wrong. That seems really strange.

Answer (score 2):

It just says, that you have a duplicate key.

Maybe it's enough to just disable flats, reindex all, enable flats, reindex all. That should be enough after i've seen your edited post

Comment: still get the same error after disabling flats.  Any idea how I could find and remove the duplicate key from the db

Comment: what if I tried to truncate catalog_product_flat?

Comment: Use PhpMyAdmin or MysqlWorkbench to find the product with product_id 2231-1in the table `cataloginventory_stock_item`. If it apears twice, you should delete the older ones.

Attention: You should always do things like this on a testing/development environment first, not on live! It may cause damage that can't be repaired.

Comment: I can't find any entry for 2231-1,  there is just an entry for 2231